# Evitar movimiento de los elementos de mi pagina html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, .net, asp

Espero puedan ayudarme, verán estoy haciendo un juego tipo mecanografía en el cual según vas escribiendo las letras correctas vas desplazando un muñequito hasta la meta. El problema es que cuando se desplaza el resto de elementos de la pagina suben, y terminan superponiendose a la imagen. Creo que se debe a que esta usa "posicion absoluta", pero segun tengo entendido es necesario para poder desplazarla. No se me ocurre que hacer ahora mismo la verdad.

Gracias de antemano!

Agrego parte del codigo:

```
function movimientoCamello(fraseUsuario){

    var camello = document.getElementById("canvas");
    recorrido = fraseUsuario.length * 90 / frases.Frase.length;

    camello.style.position = "absolute";
    camello.style.left = recorrido + '%';

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="JavaScript/JavaScript.js"></script>
    <link href="JavaScript/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title> MecanoCamello </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>- MecanoCamello -</h1>
    <h2> Pon a prueba tus habilidades </h2>

    <!-- Contenedor de la imagen de carga-->
    <div id="contenedorCarga">
        <div id="carga"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Contenedor de la imagen del camello-->
    <div id="canvas">
        <img id="camello" src="JavaScript/camello.gif" />
    </div>

    <!-- Contenedores para el los indicadores de tiempo y pulsaciones -->
    <h1 id="tiempo"></h1>
    <h1 id="pps"></h1>

    <!--Modal para pasar de frase-->
    <div id="siguienteFrase" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>"Excelente. Has terminado con éxito. ¿Desea probar el siguiente nivel?"</p>
            <button id="aceptar">Seguir jugando</button>
            <button id="cancelar">Salir</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal para repetir el nivel cuando pierde-->
    <div id="repetirNivel" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>"OOHH. Has perdido. ¿Desea probar de nuevo el nivel?"</p>
            <button id="repetir">¡Dame otra oportunidad!</button>
            <button id="salir">Pasando...</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Modal para el juego una vez acabado los niveles-->
    <div id="finalNiveles" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>"Increible. Has terminado todos los niveles. ¿Deseas volver a jugar?"</p>
            <button id="again">¡Volvamos a probar!</button>
            <button id="cerrar">Suficiente por hoy</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <br /><br />
    <br /><br />

    <!-- Contenedor donde mostramos la frase a escribir-->
    <h1 id="frase"></h1>

    <br /><br />
    <br /><br />

    <!-- Contenedor del input donde el usuario escribe, asi como donde mostramos el error si hubiese-->
    <input type="text" id="palabraIntroducida" style="width : 500px; height : 80px">
    <br /><br />
    <h1 id="errorTxt"></h1>

    <!--<button type="submit" class="button" id="btnComprobar"></button>    BOTON TEST-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tendrías que detallar algo más, añade código de la página y del script que estás usando. En principio un bloque con posición absoluta no debe desplazar al resto de los elementos. Pero sin ver algo más no puede ayudarte.

Comment: Toda la razón disculpa, y gracias por comentar. Ajunto el script que maneja el movimiento y la parte del html.

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask tu pregunta es muy pobre y no cumple con los requisitos del sitio para ser atendida, por el momento se votara para su cierre a espera de que hagas los cambios. saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que se lo que pasa, auqnue el código no es suficiente para reproducir el problema al 100%.
El bloque canvas inicialmente no está en position:absolute, sino que ocupa su posición por defecto en el flujo de la página. Al ponerle position:absolute el espacio que ocupa pasa a estar digamos libre y lo ocupa el resto de los elementos que vienen después.
Ese es el problema según veo.
Eso ocurre porque pones posicionamiento absoluto respecto a la página. Pero puedes poner posicionamiento absoluto dentro de un bloque con posicionamiento relativo y altura suficiente para alojar la imagen.
El código que puedes usar es

```
<!-- Contenedor de la imagen del camello-->
<div style="position:relative; height: 30px">
    <div id="canvas" style="position:absolute">>
        <img id="camello"  src="JavaScript/camello.gif"" />
    </div>
</div>
```

La altura del bloque contenedor debe ser la del camello al menos (he puesto 30px) y si quieres asegurar puedes ponerle también un width al tamaño que necesites o al 100%.

Comment: No es buena idea tener estilos en línea (dentro de la etiqueta), pero creo que esto resuelve el problema.

Comment: Te lo pongo con style por claridad, pero llevas razón, es recomendable usar reglas CSS. Puedes crear una clase para el contenedor de la imagen y poner la posición absoluta en el estilo canvas, o crear otra clase.

Comment: Buenas! Gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo. @Juan tu solucion funcionó perfectamente y tu explicación me servio de mucho, no se como no se me pasó por la cabeza. Tambien para proximas consultas procuraré dar mas información. Muchas gracias!!!